# PowerShell - Copy the same file for each correspondence

Tags: windows, powershell

How do I copy a file more than once to a folder using the same line of code?

I have this code here:

```
$TodayDate = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"
$TodayDateSecs = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy I hh-mm-ss"

$Sheet01 = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Sheets"
$Sheet01exists = get-ChildItem $Sheet01 -recurse | where {$_.name -match "Modelo 01 - $TodayDate"} | select name
$Project01 = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Project 01\Model 01.txt"
$WatchFolder = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Watch Folder\$ClientName"
$OldSheets = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Project 01\Old Sheets"
$MoveSheetAfterRender = get-ChildItem $Sheet01 -recurse | where {$_.name -match "Modelo 01 - $TodayDate"} | Move-Item -Destination $OldSheets

If ($Sheet01exists) {
Copy-Item -Path $Project01 -Destination "$WatchFolder\Model 01 - $TodayDateSecs.txt"
$MoveSheetAfterRender
Write-Host "Copiado para Renderização"
}
Else {
Write-Host "Arquivo não encontrado"
}
```

My intention is: every time `$Sheet01exists` returns a match I would like the file specified in `$Project01` to be copied to a folder in `$WatchFolder`.

The problem is that if there is more than one file corresponding to `$Sheet01exists` the file from `$Project01` will only be copied once.

What I need is for the file in `$Project01` to be copied to `$WatchFolder` for each match in `$Sheet01exists`. That is, it needs to be copied and renamed in order not to be overwritten.

How can I do this as cleanly as possible?

Comment: You'd be copying the file with the same name to the same folder. That would just replace it. A loop is needed, but you'd have to figure out what to do with the name of `$Project01` being copied since it would need to be renamed. Also, what would be the point of copying the same file of `$Project01` over to the same folder?

Comment: Each copied file can have an addition name like [01][02][03]... I just don't know how to do that.

The logic of copying the same file to a folder is that each of them will trigger an action in a program, if I only have one file only one action is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to go about it piping directly to a `Foreach-Object` loop:

```
$TodayDate = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"
$TodayDateSecs = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy I hh-mm-ss"

[ref]$i = 0
$Project01   = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Project 01\Model 01.txt"
$WatchFolder = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Watch Folder\$ClientName"
$OldSheets   = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Project 01\Old Sheets"

$Sheet01 = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Sheets"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Sheet01 -Filter "*Modelo 01 - $TodayDate*" -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object -Process `
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $Project01 -Destination {
            '{0}\Model 01 - {1}{2}.txt' -f $WatchFolder, $TodayDateSecs, 
                $(
                    if ($i -ne 0) 
                    {
                        '[{0:D2}]' -f $i
                    }
                    $i++
                )
        } -Verbose -WhatIf
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $OldSheets -WhatIf
    }
```

Since you're just moving the same files found out of their location onto `$OldSheets`, you can do it inside the loop by passing it the objects path. As for the files that are to be copied over, since `-Destination` accepts a scriptblock you can create a string of your own with incrementing `$i`, then appending it to the end of the path giving you the `[01]..[10]+` effect.

---

*Remove the `-WhatIf` safety/common parameter when you've dictated those are the results you're after.*

Comment: Seems to work perfectly!

Thank you very much for your attention and patience to explain!

Comment: @TyroneHirt, glad it worked for you.